# Porque cuando linkeo bootstrap rompe mis media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas en mi portfolio agregue el cdn de Bootstrap y cuando lo hago, mis media queries dejan de funcionar y en la consola me aparece que una constante de JS es null.

Este es mi header:

```
<header>
        <a href="" class="brand">Mateo</a>
        <div class="menu-btn"></div>
        
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#main">Home</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
                <a href="#work">Work</a>
                <a href="#axis">Axis</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
    </header>
```

Y este es mi script que utilizo para hacer un responsive nav:

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");
const navigationItems = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation a");

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    menuBtn.classList.toggle('active');
    navigation.classList.toggle('active');
});

navigationItems.forEach((navigationItem) => {
    navigationItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        menuBtn.classList.remove("active");
        navigation.classList.remove("active");
    });
});
```

Antes funcionaba perfecto pero ahora parece que mi constante menuBtn es null.

```
Uncaught TypeError: menuBtn is null
```

Dejo un snipett con mi código.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");
const navigationItems = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation a");

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    menuBtn.classList.toggle('active');
    navigation.classList.toggle('active');
});

navigationItems.forEach((navigationItem) => {
    navigationItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        menuBtn.classList.remove("active");
        navigation.classList.remove("active");
    });
});
```

```html
<header>
        <a href="" class="brand">Mateo</a>
        <div class="menu-btn"></div>
        
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#main">Home</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
                <a href="#work">Work</a>
                <a href="#axis">Axis</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
    </header>
```

Dejo tambien el link de mi portfolio también por si quieren ver el comportamiento de la página que se rompe en un width de 1040px

```
https://mateoghidini1998.github.io/
```

Comment: Bootstrap tiene todo lo que puedas necesitar (menú responsive, header, cards, etc.) sin necesidad de agregar nada de CSS ni JS. Hay conflicto porque Bootstrap tal vez detecta sus propias clases en el HTML.  Si necesitas tu propio estilo, debe ser muy diferente a la de Bootstrap para que no haya conflictos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estas pisando tu propio código.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta claro que puedes usar las mismas clases de bootstrap puede que debido a los nombres encuentres problemas pero no es algo de que preocuparse hasta que se presenten